# Cannot interpolate ruby variable into string url to call JSON API

Tags: ruby, json, api, httparty

I'm trying to make a GET request to a JSON api, iterating over a number of JSON objects to extract their ids and then input them into the url to make the request. The token part works fine, but there is something wrong with my each iterator which I can't figure out.

An example GET url for this api request is:
https://api.hailoapp.com/business/read?id=12345

The api should return a valid response but I keep getting a 400 error which the api doc says, means there is no id. So there must be something wrong with my code:

```
require "json"
require "httparty"

# LOGIN

login_response = HTTParty.post("https://api.hailoapp.com/auth/login",
  {
  :body => { :user => "email@email.com", :password => "password" }.to_json,
  :headers => { "Content-Type" => "text", "Accept" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
  })

data = login_response.to_hash
api_token = data["api_token"]

# RETRIEVE ACCOUNT

restaurants = JSON.parse File.read('file.json')

input_id = restaurants.each do |r| r["id"]
  retrieve_response = HTTParty.get("https://api.hailoapp.com/business/read?id=#{input_id}",
  {
    :headers => { "Content-Type" => "text", "Accept" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization" => "token #{api_token}" }
  }) 
  puts retrieve_response.body
  puts retrieve_response.code
  puts retrieve_response.message
end
```

I tried this in the console: `restaurants.each { |r| puts r["id"] }` but don't know how to make it work together with the main code to access the api.

Example JSON data:

```
  {
      "id": "137072",
      "name": "The Brackenbury",
      "phone": "+442087414928",
      "email": "table@brackenburyrestaurant.co.uk",
      "website": "http://brackenburyrestaurant.co.uk/",
      "location": {
          "latitude": 51.4978732,
          "longitude": -0.2313129,
          "address": {
              "line1": "129-131 Brackenbury Road",
              "line2": "Hammersmith",
              "line3": "",
              "postcode": "W6 0BQ",
              "city": "London",
              "country": "UK"
          }
      }
  }
```

When I did a similar POST request to the api using this code, it worked fine.

Comment: are you sure the way you are looping around `input_id = restaurants.each do |r| r["id"]`  is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code ...

```
retrieve_response = HTTParty.get("https://api.hailoapp.com/business/read?id=#{input_id}",
{
  :headers => { "Content-Type" => "text", "Accept" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization" => "token #{api_token}" }
  })
```

References a variable called `input_id`but that's actually the whole iteration not each instance.

What you want is...

```
retrieve_response = HTTParty.get("https://api.hailoapp.com/business/read?id=#{r[:id]}",
{
  :headers => { "Content-Type" => "text", "Accept" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization" => "token #{api_token}" }
  })
```

Which will retrieve the response for each instance of the iteration (the instance is called `r`) using r's `:id` value.

You don't need the standalone `r[:id]` at the top of the each block, remove that.

Comment: Thanks @SteveTurczn, so I just do this at the top of the block: `restaurants.each do |r|` and then interpolate with: `#{r[:id]` and then end at the bottom?

Comment: That works great @SteveTurczyn thanks v. much, you are the man! haha